# Is it possible to break a sentence without it taking up extra space at the end?

Tags: html, css

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 72px;
}
```

```html
<p>this is a long sentence</p>
<p>small word sentence</p>
```

I need the two elements to have the same styles but I want the elements to not leave any extra space to the right like the first element is doing. 
Can this be achieved in any way? Also the words cannot break.
Thanks!

Comment: add  `word-break: break-all;`

Comment: @demkovych please read the question

Comment: It's not possible. You can only justify text and break words: `text-align: justify;
    word-break: break-all;`

Comment: the duplicate aren't related to your exact example but they will give the answer which is *no you cannot* since the behavior is the same for any line break content